# IP address location indoors

Tags: web-applications

I need to track the IP location for each user that login to my website. I need to know their location inside a building, for example a user is inside room A, so the IP location should be "room A".
To be more specific i need to know the location for each student which login to my website. I looked at google maps indoors, but is not implemented in my country.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is by getting a map of the IP's in the building. Try finding out if there is an IP range for each room, if so then you can check if the IP is in that range and then you can map that too the room. The seating position however you will need a map of all the IP's. Also keep in mind the IP's may change.